# Material Colors don't show when exporting?

Tags: materials

I have this model here and instead of textures I've just assigned materials to different parts of the mesh and gave them plain colors. But when I export it in any format, fbx or obj or gltf, when I try to upload it to sketchfab or mixamo or even try to open it in microsoft 3D viewer, it just shows a blank version of my model.
When I import what I exported, it still has the materials but their colors are gone and instead of "Emission" they're now "Principled BDSF". How do I solve this problem? Thank you.

[image: My model and the materials next to it]

[image: Exported as FBX]

**EDIT**:
Moderators: I have already checked the question provided and all the other questions, they say it's not possible but I've seen people do it on YouTube like Grant Abbitt on his "how to rig the easy way" video.
So I've checked quite a lot of questions on this matter but it still doesn't solve my problem. (Also important to mention that I'm very new to 3D stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most exporters will only handle very basic Principled BSDF materials. You can make a Principled material that will look like you want by putting black in the "Base Color" socket and putting the color you want in the "Emission" socket. (You may also want to try cranking the roughness up to 1.)

[image: Principled material]

I tried exporting this with .fbx/.obj/.glb and reimporting, and they all worked.

[image: Original monkey + monkey reimported from .fbx/.obj/.glb. They all look the same.]

Comment: Thank you so much!